# Receiving a text message in Rails app (Twilio SMS)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sms, twilio

Does anybody have any example code on how this would work?  Seems like it should be pretty straightforward, but the Twilio documentation is sparse for SMS/Rails.

I have a simple "post" model with a "body" column and "from" column.  I just want to display the SMS messages in a list.  The closest thing I got to work was something like this:

```
#posts_controller.rb
class PostsController < ApplicationController
 def new
   @post = Post.new(:body=>"?",:from=>"?")
   @post.save
 end
end

#twilio sms url: ...myappurl/posts/new
```

This creates a new post, but the 'from' and 'body' values are "?", obviously.  How do I pass the Twilio SMS 'From' and 'Body' values into the rails controller?

Any ideas or a nudge in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just solved it!  It was as simple as I thought it was.

In my `posts_controller.rb` file:

```
def twilio_create
  @post = Post.new(:body => params[:Body], :from => params[:From])
  @post.save
end
```

This effectively pulls the `Body` and `From` params from Twilio.  The same can be applied for other params (`SmsMessageSid`, `AccountSid`, etc).

You can see the full list of parameters sent with Twilio's request [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/twilio_request).

Comment: Three quick notes: 1) You should adhere to standard Ruby conventions, especially when posting public code (spaces around operators/etc); 2) You can use `Post.create ( <data> )` instead of using two separate calls if you aren't going to use a conditional to verify and perform an action within the method; 3) Using capitalized symbols is awkward – consider using lowercased input field names.

Thanks for sharing the answer once you found it, and welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Thanks!  I am planning on using conditionals within the methods , and regarding (3) - those specific capitalized symbols are required to work with Twilio.  Lowercase symbols don't work - I just tested it.